# Is "language: lang-ada" not fully implemented, or buggy?

Tags: support, feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I saw [a post on Meta about the syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109) and noticed that I could add `<!-- language-all: lang-ada -->` to [ada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ada)-tagged posts to add colored syntax highlighting. However, `lang-ada` wasn't listed in the answer I linked, and it doesn't seem to be working properly, nor is it added automatically to posts tagged [ada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ada), which the post claims should be happening.

Example of not working properly:

```ada
-- This is a comment, which is not being highlighted consistently (this not if then for etc.)

-- "Ticks" highlight the rest of the line in brown, presumably looking for a closing tick
-- Highlighting from single tick carries over into the next line
if Thing'Value("None") = None then
if Thing'Value("None") = None then
if Thing'Value("None") = None then -- ' Back to (lack of) comment highlighting
if Thing''Value("None") = None then -- highlighting is different because of the closed single tick
```

Comment: Not sure about these Meta tags, feel free to edit & correct

Comment: Did you read the post you linked about how to address issues with posts not being highlighted correctly?

Comment: I'm confused. You read the answer and that language hint is not listed there, so why are you still trying to use it as if it should work? Our syntax highlighter only supports the hints listed at the bottom of that answer. Anything else reverts to default and is implicitly unsupported.

Comment: @animuson I saw other [tag:Ada] posts using it. It does not highlight code at all without the `language-all` specifier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is “language: lang-ada” not fully implemented, or bugged?

#### No, this is not a bug. It is not fully implemented. In fact, it is not implemented at all.

The following quotes are extracted from the meta answer you linked to

> This is a complete list of every identifier that you can use in the language hint for syntax highlighting

This statement explicitly means the every identifier which is not in that list cannot be used for syntax highlighting.

As you have stated, lang-ada is not in that list, hence it cannot be used for syntax highlighting. As such, the syntax highlighter will default to:

> default generic highlighter that works passably on most C-like languages and HTML-like markup languages.

If this *was* a bug, this would not be the place to report it:

> If it is indeed a bug in the syntax highlighter itself, check the [issues list](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues) to see if it has already been reported. If it hasn't, feel free to report it or [join the project](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/graphs/contributors) and submit a fix yourself. If you want to ensure that an issue you raised is fixed quickly, it's best to include the fix in the report. If the fix has already been implemented by Prettify but is still not working here, please raise a feature request on Meta to request that a new version of Prettify be deployed.

If you would like lang-ada to be implemented:

> You can also submit a request for a new language to be added in [that same issues list](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues). Keep in mind that Stack Exchange does not maintain this syntax highlighter, and posting bug reports or feature requests concerning it here on Meta will not get them fixed or implemented.